# I found it surprising that ... vs I was surprised that

Tags: meaning, differences

> I found it surprising that she sang well.
>
> I was surprised that[because] she sang well.

When you translate them in Japanese, the two sentences become the same in meaning.
I feel there’s a difference but I’m not sure. Could you explain that?

Comment: It's either *that* ***or*** *because*. The combination of the two doesn't work. (And that makes it more than just one variable you're changing, so it's not clear which component you're actually comparing between the two sentence.)

Comment: They're functionally equivalent.  And here's yet another that means the same thing: *I was surprised she sang so well*.

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503909/i-find-it-surprising-that-i-was-surprised-that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native English speaker: they mean exactly the same thing. I can’t think of any nuance of meaning that differentiates them.